# Search YouTube favorites?

Tags: youtube, google-chrome, firefox

Is it possible to search my YouTube favorites using Chrome or Firefox without an extension?"

Can anybody that has Chrome and can actually do it, answer? Also, for Firefox (latest version of ff), only those that can do it.

**Added 2023**

I searched a while back and found a website or two that did but more recently i've not found anything and certainly nothing in the youtube interface, though i've tried many options in the youtube interface.

I'm going to respond to a comment for me to be more specific. A comment said "Please be more specific about the Web browser features that you are trying to use, i.e, if you are trying to search from URL / address bar or using the Find in page feature. Show what you have tried and what you found on YouTube, and each web browser help."

To answer the question of whether I am trying to "search from the address bar" .  No i'm not, and I don't think there is really such a thing.  Sometimes people when they type a search term in the address bar it does a google search. I'm not talking about that.

As for whether i'm looking for a "find in page" feature, no i'm not. Youtube doesn't show all videos on one page.  A person could have 50 pages of youtube videos.

As for what i've found on youtube when looking for searching favorites, there is this video here [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GSMDpgdGOs4)  "How to find favourites on YouTube (November 2020)"   It mentions that the favourites list is now under playlists. But it doesn't talk about how to search favorites.

There's another video "How To Find Your Watch Later Playlist On YouTube - Mobile & PC" by  GuideRealm  [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x8BvAj6q2Hk&ab_channel=GuideRealm)  And it mentions that if clicking on the three lines, then it opens a menu showing "watch later" and "liked videos".

So from those it looks like "liked videos" is the current name for "favorites".

Another video "How to see all YouTube likes if you liked over 5,000 videos" By Bhupinder Tube

Mentions that you can list all watch history https://myactivity.google.com/product/youtube?utm_source=my-activity   Though that's not searching "liked"/favourites

There is a search there when looking at watch history, but I see no way to search specifically for liked videos.

And the video mentions that you can list all liked videos, https://myactivity.google.com/page?utm_source=my-activity&hl=en_GB&page=youtube_comment_likes

but doesn't show a search for it. And "find in page" / ctrl-f won't do it because it doesn't show all results on one page. You'd have to keep holding page down for potentially hours or days.

Comment: i'd suggest not using youtube favorites.. it has a limitation on how many. So better to have a txt file.

Comment: The accepted answer starts saying "I'm guessing your question is, "Is it possible to search my YouTube favorites using Chrome or Firefox without an extension?"". Is that correct?

Comment: @Rubén Yes, and they didn't have to guess, because the question says "I'm not looking for somebody just pointing to an extension,..."    I have now made it clearer though

Comment: Please be more specific about the Web browser features that you are trying to use, i.e, if you are trying to search from URL / address bar or using the Find in page feature. Show what you have tried and what you found on YouTube, and each web browser help.

Comment: @Rubén  thanks i've now added more research and addressed those questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To answer your question of - "Is it possible to search my YouTube favorites using Chrome or Firefox without an extension?"

The answer is no. YouTube doesn't currently provide a way to search favorites.

Advanced search options are on the search results page but nothing to let you search your favorites.

Answer (score 3):

### Specs

Go to ->

> PLaylist Settings (of Favorites) -> Advanced Settings

.
Youtube allows you there fetch your list (Click read more). Save the list locally.
Code your utility that searches the HTML list to obtain URL and location.
:)

Search extract for -> `<tr with class="pl-video yt-uix-tile "`
and attribute **data-title=** and anchor **a href=**.

p.s. I know, not being much useful here. **:))**

Comment: Thanks. Does youtube still limit how many favourites you can have?  youtube is very unreliable because they can always add/remove/cripple features at will

Answer (score 3):

As all these options seem to have gone dysfunct in 2020, for anyone who just wants to get this/any/all data out of the google dark net:

https://takeout.google.com/ allows you to export your complete personal data from all their services, including your youtube playlists in JSON format.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple way; Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and while holding it down press the <kbd>F</kbd> key on your keyboard and a small window will open at the bottom of the screen. Type what song or artist you are looking for in the search box --- voila! Alternatively you can use Edit if your browser has the Menu Bar visible. FYI this will work in about all Windows programs and all the search engines.

Comment: Won't this only search in the current page? What if there are multiple pages of favourites?

Comment: people typically have hundreds of favorites. how many will that allow searching through?

Comment: As long as you keep pressing load more at the bottom of the page, you will eventually get all your videos on one page and use this to find what you're looking for. Worked for me to find one I liked a few years ago.