# Is there a way to search through liked videos on my YouTube account?

Tags: youtube, search, youtube-playlist

Is there a way to search for specific videos in my like playlist on my account?

Comment: Hey OP I was wondering if you tried using good ol' ctrl+F? It searches the entire page for keywords without having to download extra software.

Comment: Still no way to do it without an extension? Search within youtube is terrible.

Comment: There's still no native way to do this. I'm embarrassed to say I did this and it worked, but scrolling for about 45 seconds loaded about 3 years of videos for me, and I was able to cmd-F through all those videos at once. YMMV if you like videos substantially more often than I do though.

Answer (score 14):

For me I found that [History](https://www.youtube.com/feed/history) page have search at the right:

[image: youtube history search]

Comment: Searching the history, searches every video the user has watched but is not restricted to those they "liked". The results of a history search do not make it obvious which got the thumbs up and which did not.

Answer (score 11):

Update: As of August 31 2023, the YouTube playlist search script is unfortunately no longer available.

---

If you have a user script manager like Greasemonkey installed, you can use the aptly named [**YouTube Playlist Search**](https://greasyfork.org/en/scripts/14370-youtube-playlist-search) to search through your [liked videos playlist](https://www.youtube.com/my_liked_videos).

> Quickly search and filter through the items in a playlist (like watch
> later or favorites). Search includes the title of the video and the
> user it was uploaded by. It will hide/show the playlist items as you
> type, empty the text box to show all items.
>
> [image: YouTube Playlist Search script]

*If you don't know how to install user scripts, [see this helpful guide](https://greasyfork.org/en/help/installing-user-scripts)*

Comment: This plugin does only search the "visible" videos. So for a playlist that has more than 100 videos, You still need to manually scroll down the browser window (hit the END key repeatedly until nothing new shows up), and only then it searches in every video of the playlist.

Comment: This becomes tedious after few hundred videos, not to mention like 3k, 10k or more. Liking videos is for the algorithm rather than end-users.

Comment: Not too mention that YouTube seems to crawl to a halt if you are trying to get too much content on the page.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from this [suggestion](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/143079/171892), go to
https://takeout.google.com/ and click the "Deselect all" hyperlink, scrolling to the end of the page to check "YouTube and YouTube Music."
[image: Youtube Content Options]
With the "Multiple formats" button below, premium users may get an alternative to `csv` in their output. just to the right of it there is an "All youtube data included" button. Click it, (see graphic) again click "Deselect all" at the top, select *playlists* below, and click the ok button.
Optionally check *[music-library-songs](https://music.youtube.com/library/songs)*, as that file contains the full url and the video description, which the playlist does not have.
Click "Next Step" below, and, then if the defaults seem reasonable, click "Export".
The export duration should be short, after which a username/password prompt is provided for file access. Navigate to the Downloads location for the `takeout-yyyymmddid_number-001.zip` and navigate the the folders in the zipped archive *\Takeout\YouTube and YouTube Music\playlists* to `Liked videos.csv`, and also, optionally, to the `music-library-songs.csv` in the adjacent directory.
The *music-library-songs* appears to be a more recent addition in the personal collection, thus the liked videos only go back 2-3 years or so. This is an instantly searchable list, whereas older video ids in the *playlist* must be ported to a search script where they will be url encoded for web verification.

Comment: To date, no evidence of liked youtube albums posted as videos appearing in [music-library-albums](https://music.youtube.com/library/albums).
 Possibility of later adding a search script with AHK/wget or similar.

Answer (score 1):

Here: very ezy https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/playlist-search-for-youtu/jdolgjncmhmboklhmacpknglmiibbldg

1. Make click on the link above, click on "Add to Chrome", confirm the pop-up.
2. Then you need to pin the extension (the puzzle icon in the right above corner of your google chrome windows), make a click on the logo of the extension and sign-in with your google account.
3. each time you need to use it, you have to click on the extension, it will list all the videos on your current youtube tab. And I mean ALL of them, I have more than 2500 videos on my liked videos playlist and it works perfectly, it also works for other playlists you made, not only liked videos.

Answer (score -3):

click ctrl F in your browser window a search window appears in google browser type in the keyword looking for in the liked videos

p.s make sure you are in the liked videos display page in your browser window

Comment: That won't work if you have hundreds of liked videos.

Comment: If you hold `Command` and keep pressing the `down` arrow, you can quickly load hundreds of liked videos on the page. It took me less than 30 seconds to load 2k liked videos. `Ctrl + f` worked like a charm.

Answer (score -7):

When I  search for specific videos on youtube i go to:

**Settings -> (under the category LIBRARY) -> Liked videos.**

That  should give you your liked videos.

Comment: I believe the OP is asking for how to search for videos *within* the liked videos playlist, not how to find the playlist itself

Comment: That is correct