# Searching and filtering through all videos in my saved youtube playlists

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

**Question 1:** Is there a way to easily make a search through all the videos in my saved playlists for a free account?

**Question 2:** Would any yt front-end (open source, e.g. from [here](https://github.com/mendel5/alternative-front-ends)) allow me to easily import all my user data from a yt account (specifically all saved videos, playlists, liked videos and subscriptions) and further include a recursive playlist search?

### Description

I have 300 saved playlists, both created by me and others, all are of course visible if I go to the side menu and click 'show all', and so I can easily find a certain playlist with ctrl-f, but I want a way to just search for words (preferably with boolean options) say '"quotient rings"' and get videos from my saved playlists.

For (1) I found a few things that are close, but not entirely right:

[Youtube Playlist Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-playlist-helper/)
I can easily create new playlists from my already saved playlists, but I cannot seem to just import all my saved playlists; I would have to go one by one. Also, it seems I can only search for a playlist name and not recursively.

There are also an extensive list of [alternative front-ends to youtube](https://github.com/mendel5/alternative-front-ends) with things like invidious, which I guess I haven't exhausted, but it seems tricky to directly import all my playlists into one and then I'm still not sure which one would allow me to do a recursive search through the playlists.

Scrolling through [this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9471/search-youtube-favorites) (from 2010 so perhaps not still accurate) I also found an answer that links to https://takeout.google.com/ where you can request a json file with everything. This would possibly be ok as a workaround as I can then just search through the text files. But not really feasible in the long run, since I constantly add new videos.

EDIT: With takeout one can only download the csv files and they only contain links and no meta-data like video titles etc. Also, I tried using an alternative front-end like piped and invidious, but neither of them worked when I tried to import the csv files, even though the option is there. Also, one can only import one playlist at a time.

It sounds like it would be a pretty easy thing to automate though, just fetch all saved playlists as a huge json/csv, and search through it. But I don't know any js and wouldn't really know if it's easy to just fetch like that anyway. One could download the csv files and write a script that goes through every link and just return the video title, but again, it would be cleaner if this could be done without having to first export everything via takeout.